# Compare 2 files using awk-If 2nd field is same,sum the 1st field & print it-if not print it(true for non-matching entries in both the files)

Tags: linux, unix, awk, compare

I have two files -

File 1:

> 2 923000026531
>
> 1 923000031178
>
> 2 923000050000
>
> 1 923000050278
>
> 1 923000051178
>
> 1 923000060000

File 2:

> 2 923000050000
>
> 3 923000050278
>
> 1 923000051178
>
> 1 923000060000
>
> 4 923000026531
>
> 1 923335980059

I want to achieve the following using awk:

1- If 2nd field is same, sum the 1st field and print it.

2- If 2nd field is not same, print the line as it is. This will have two cases.

2(a) If 2nd field is not same & record belongs to first file

2(b) If 2nd field is not same & record belongs to second file

I have achieved the following using this command:

> Command: gawk 'FNR==NR{f1[$2]=$1;next}$2 in f1{print f1[$2]+$1,$2}!($2 in f1){print $0}' f1 f2
>
> Result:
>
> 4 923000050000
>
> 4 923000050278
>
> 2 923000051178
>
> 2 923000060000
>
> 6 923000026531
>
> 1 923335980059

However, this doesn't contains the records which were in first file & whose second field didn't match that of the second file  i.e. case 2(a), to be more specific, the following record is not present in the final file:

> 1 923000031178

I know there are multiple work around using extra commands but I am interested if this can be somehow done in the same command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

give this one-liner a try:

```
$ awk '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(x in a)print a[x], x}' f1 f2
2 923000060000
2 923000051178
1 923000031178
6 923000026531
4 923000050278
4 923000050000
1 923335980059
```

Comment: mind to explain why the answer gets downvoted? it gives the expected output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know who downvoted that though :/

Comment: Question: in your opinion is there a faster way to do it? I have files containing upto 40 million entries at least.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah we have to go through all lines in two files before printing the output, because we need to find out and sum all the dups.

Comment: I understand that - the procedure runs fine for 10 million numbers, I however have 40 million numbers. :(